# Bootstrap: Collapse tab list to dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a page with twitter bootstrap that contains 2 columns using the grid system. On the left side, I have a stacked pill list (using class .nav-stacked).  When the page's width is under 768px the right column with the content falls under the stacked pills and the stacked pills fill up the full width, which I like.

What I need is when the page is under 768, the stacked pills collapse and shows the toggle button (button with 3 lines). How can I accomplish this? I feel like i'm missing a class or something, heh

The code in it's most basic form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/link.html">Link 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/link.html">Link 2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/link.html">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        MY CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar might help you

Comment: I looked at that, but I couldn't get the navbar to work with .nav-stacked =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/ZYOjbL) ([Full page view](http://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/full/ZYOjbL), better for testing the responsive functionality). Is that what you're looking for?

Code for posterity:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default xs-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pills">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked xs-collapse" id="pills">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/link.html">Link 1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/link.html">Link 2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/link.html">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        MY CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.xs-collapse {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .xs-toggle {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .xs-collapse {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

/* Styles for toggle button (optional) */

.xs-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.xs-toggle .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.btn-default.xs-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}
```

So basically what this does is recreate the style used for the navbar toggle functionality in a more generic format. The classes `xs-toggle` and `xs-collapse` have been created to signify the toggle functionality taking effect on screen sizes < 768px (the same as the `xs` classes in Bootstrap use by default). You could therefore expand this to other responsive widths by adding the appropriate `sm`, `lg`, etc. style versions. The rest of the style is for the toggle button itself. It's a special case scenario in Bootstrap for the navbar only. You could drop these and make the button look however you like.